# Angular 2 templates methods vs getters

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, getter-setter

I'm wondering if there is any benefit to do this:

```
  <div>{{getSomething()}}</div>

  export class MyComp {
    getSomething() { return ...}
  }
```

Over this:

```
 <div>{{getSomething}}</div>

 export class MyComp {
   get getSomething() { return ...}
 }
```

Use methods vs getters to display calculated data.

Comment: I think this is just a syntactic sugar for the same thing.  Did you see somewhere that the is any benefit using one of them?

Comment: No, this is my question, I am trying to understand if there is a different.

Comment: would not use a getter in a template. It makes it less clear that a calculation is being performed every change detection and can make it harder to detect performance issues. For example, {{ name }} could really be a complex getter that takes half a second to run. I'd rather write {{ name() }} which makes it clear that there is code being executed, and allow me to spot and improve performance issues later. It can get really easy to slow down an angular application with it's eager change detection, so be mindful of that.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

I looked deeper into this and played with typescript Playground.
I declared two classes one with getter and the second with get method as described in your questions.

Lets see how it looks like:

In the first example we declared a method for getting the property value in the following way:

```
class Greeter {
  greeting: string;
  constructor(message: string) {
      this.greeting = message;
  }
   getGreeting() {
      return this.greeting;
  }
}
```

Which after translation to javascript it looks like:

```
var Greeter = (function () {
   function Greeter(message) {
       this.greeting = message;
   }
   Greeter.prototype.getGreeting = function () {
       return this.greeting;
   };
   return Greeter;
}());
```

And regarding the second example where we declared a getter in the following way:

```
class GetterGreeter {
   _greeting: string;
   constructor(message: string) {
       this._greeting = message;
   }
    get greeting() {
       return this._greeting;
   }
}
```

Which after translation looks like:

```
var GetterGreeter = (function () {
   function GetterGreeter(message) {
       this._greeting = message;
   }
   Object.defineProperty(GetterGreeter.prototype, "greeting", {
       get: function () {
           return this._greeting;
       },
       enumerable: true,
       configurable: true
   });
   return GetterGreeter;
}());
```

(You can play with the declaration and the translation to javascript [here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=class%20Greeter%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20greeting%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(message%3A%20string)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.greeting%20%3D%20message%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20getGreeting()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this.greeting%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20GetterGreeter%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20_greeting%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(message%3A%20string)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this._greeting%20%3D%20message%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20get%20greeting()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this._greeting%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D))

As you can see with get method (as in your first example) the method is declared on the prototype and in your second example using the getter pattern typescript uses the defineProperty api.

In both cases we are invoking a method and angular will also call a method during its change detection to identify changes and re-render.

As I see it this is only a syntactic sugar for the same approach and I don't see any performance benefit for one of the methods.

Comment: The getter returns a new array everytime called. Does the normal method also return a new array everytime? For example, would `getSomething() { return this.someArray}` return a new array even when there is no change in someArray?

Answer (score 33):

If you are a getter or a method doesn't matter from a technical point of view.

Some use the convention that a getter should behave similar to a field, and not do expensive computation, while a method should be used if the computation is more than some very basic things like for example building a full name from first- middle- and last name.

I think this is good practice to follow that distinction for Angular, because for view binding expensive calculation should be avoided because the method or getter can be called very often.
In such a case it's better to store the result in a field and bind to the field instead.

Very important in view binding is, that the method or getter doesn't return different values on subsequent calls when no dependencies were modified (like `return {};`, which would be treated as new object instance and cause an error like `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError`).

Comment: I think you meant "I think this is **not** a good practice for Angular". Meaning we shouldn't use methods/getters in the template. I may have misunderstood that :-)

Comment: Actually, I did mean as I wrote it, but thanks for the hint that it wasn't clear enough what I meant. Using getters and methods in binding isn't bad by itself, but binding to fields is even more efficient. My main point was that binding to expensive method calls should definitely be avoided.

Comment: Would it be a expensive method one that makes a Array.filter() operation? As in a view where you want to filter main data by some field.

Comment: If you bind to the method in the view directly, then probably yes (less with `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`). It will be called every time change detection is run. If you apply the filter and assign the result to a field and bind to that field instead it will be much more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

by `get` / `set` syntax the method behaves like a field, see below examples:

**Using by regular getter method**

```
usingGetterMethod()
{
  let id = this.getId();
}

getId()
{
  return this.reactiveForm.get('id');
}
```

**Using by get method**

```
usingGetMethod()
{
  let id = this.id;
}

get id()
{
  return this.reactiveForm.get('id');
}
```

Answer (score -2):

The difference is in the first case you use a function in expression, but in the second case you use a peoperty. So you can use

```
<div>{{something}}</div>

export class MyComp {
  get something() { return ...}
}
```

---

The benefits of using second method is to use encapsulation of the property inside the class and you need to access it outside the class.

Getters and setters are part of ES5 spec. You can read about [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) and [setter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set).

Comment: With a getter you'd access it in the template with `<div>{{ getSomething }}</div>`. You treat it as an attribute not a function.

Comment: @Simon It can't be attribute if it's a function and vice versa.

Comment: I said it was _treated_ like an attribute/property: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45648714/how-to-access-getter-setter-accessors-from-angular-4-in-template-binding

If you have `get getSomething() {}` and use `{{ getSomething() }}` in your template you are going to have a bad time since getters are not callable.