# How to access getter/setter accessors from angular 4 in template binding?

Tags: angular, typescript, getter-setter, templatebinding

Lets say I have the following getter/setter methods

```js
get next() {
  console.log(this.people[this._index], this._index);
  return this.people[this._index];
}

set next(i: any) {
  this._index = (+i) + 1;
  this._index = (+i) % this.people.length;
}
```

and I want to call this in the following way:

```html
<ng-template ngFor let-person="$implicit" [ngForOf]="people" let-i=index let-last=last>
  <app-card [cardItem]="people[i]" [nextCard]="next(i)"></app-card>
</ng-template>
```

PS: Think of this as circular array. Where by I need prev, current, and next items.

However I get the following Error

> Angular: Member 'next' in not callable

Why is that? And whats the solution?

Thanks

## Edit

Thank you guys for your help and explanation. With your help i managed to make it work:

```html
<app-card [currentCard]="people[i]" [nextCard]="people[i === people.length - 1 ? 0: i + 1]" [prevCard]="i == 0 ? people[people.length - 1] : people[i - 1]"></app-card>
```

So its pretty much circular array.
Lets assume we have the following:

`people["James Dan", "Aluan Haddad", "Jota Toledo"]`

So few conditions:

1. If I stand in the beginning of the array (i.e. `index = 0`) - then my `prev` will be `people[people.length - 1]` which is the last element in the array. And if my current is on index 1, then my prev will be index 0 and next will be index 2.

Comment: I added one more example to my answer. This shows how you would actually use a property correctly and demonstrates building a display structure while keeping the complexity out of the template.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The Angular template syntax is, in general, a subset of JavaScript syntax with some notable differences and with many restrictions.

However what you have here is actually invalid in JavaScript as well. It is not valid to call a property accessor. Ever.

Given the following property

```
get p() {
  console.info('read p');
  return this.wrapped;
}
set p(value) {
  console.info('wrote p');
  this.wrapped = value;
}
```

The `get` accessor is invoked implicitly when the property thusly named is read.

For example:

```
console.log(o.p); // read p
```

The `set` accessor is invoked implicitly when the property thusly named is written.

For example:

```
o.p = x; // wrote p;
```

The same rules apply in Angular templates.

However, your example of

```
<app-card [cardItem]="people[i]" [nextCard]="next(i)">
```

suggests that a property is not what you want here.

The correct usage of a property implies the following syntax

```
<app-card [cardItem]="people[i]" [nextCard]="next = i">
```

Which I do not believe is supported by the Angular template syntax and even if it is doesn't make a lot of sense and would be hard to read.

Instead you should create a method that returns a value

```
getNext(i: number) {
  this._index = i + 1;
  this._index = i % this.people.length;
  return this.people[this._index];
}
```

Then used in your template as

```
<app-card [cardItem]="people[i]" [nextCard]="getNext(i)">
```

Having said that, I think the entire design is questionable. You seem to be going through contortions to store excess mutable state independently of the array that naturally maintains it.

I believe you would be much better served by removing the method and the property entirely and using

```
<app-card
  *ngFor="let person of people; let i = index"
  [previousCard]="people[i === 0 ? people.length - 1 : i - 1]" 
  [cardItem]="person"
  [nextCard]="people[i === people.length - 1 ? 0 : i + 1]">
```

If you want a cleaner syntax, you might define a property, with a `get` accessor only, that returns a view of your array as objects with `previous`, `current`, and `next` properties.

```
get peopleAsPreviousCurrentAndNextTriplets() {
  return this.people.map((person, i) => ({
    previous: this.people[i === 0 ? this.people.length - 1 : i - 1],
    current: person,
    next: this.people[i === this.people.length - 1 ? 0 : i + 1]
  }));
}
```

This can be more readable in complex code because its abstracts away the index for more semantic properties that we can use directly. Perhaps more importantly, it enables TypeScript's world-class tooling to validate the computation.

```
<app-card
  *ngFor="let item of peopleAsPreviousCurrentAndNextTriplets"
  [previousCard]="item.previous" 
  [cardItem]="item.current"
  [nextCard]="item.next">
```

And thus we come full circle. Note how we define the `get` accessor and how we read the property it defines without `()`, implicitly invoking that accessor.

The last example is probably overkill for this scenario but I think it's useful nonetheless.

Comment: the approach with the getNext method is necessary, as op wants to get the item at index 0 for the item at index array.length apparently

Comment: @Jota.Toledo I still don't think you need a get accessor. It is never read by his example code. A method might be necessary.

Comment: Sorry, expressed my idea in a wrong way. I meant what you just said :D

Comment: Lol, apologies, didnt give too much attention to your answer. Thank you for your thorough explanation. So I decided to opt my whol answer based on your review. and now Im planning to get next and prev directly.

As for next: we have `people[(i + 1) % people.length]` which works fine

Comment: however, as for prev, not sure why it gives me undefined

Comment: @James so you want both the person before and the person after as well as the current person then? In a circular structure?

Comment: @James your question doesnt mention anything about prev. Update your question if thats part of it...

Comment: Correct @AluanHaddad Yes, thats what i want

Comment: @James take a look at the code at the end of my answer I think that will do the job.

Comment: Thank you, you've won this question :)

Comment: @James glad to help