# How to pass data from one component to another dynamically without "Parent-Child" relationship in Angular 2+?

Tags: angular, typescript

This is somewhat an open discussion but I'm really curious about passing data dynamically from one component to another.

I know it can be done using `@Input()` decorator. But it has its disadvantages like you can't use the back button on your browser. Because if you do, then you will do back an entire page. It won't work in the `Parent-Child` method because we're using `ng-If` to hide the child directives on a page and It won't update the content dynamically unless you reload that page. And when you reload that page, you lose the current state of the UI.

If the data is static then there's absolutely no problem but when it's dynamic and you try to pass the data, it shows as `undefined`.

I would appreciate any pointers on how would I be able to achieve that.

Comment: This is what services are for..?

Comment: I tried passing dynamic data from a component by adding that component in the providers array and then access that property in another component, it showed `undefined` again. Maybe the way I was using it was incorrect. Could you refer me such an example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another way is using a **service**. You have to use the service as a "store" of your data values:

1. Create a service:

```
ng g s MyServiceName --skip-Tests
```

Once it is created, check that has been decorated as providedIn root:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class MyServiceNameService {
....
```

2. In your service, declare all data you want the components share (have in commun), and create methods setters/getters for this data.
   e.g:

```
private _myVariable: string;

get myVariable(){
   return _myVariable;
}

set myVariable(newValue: string){
   this._myVariable = newValue;
}

constructor(){
   _myVariable = "exampletest";
}
```

3. Inject the service in the constructor of your components (in parent and in child):

```
...
import { MyServiceNameService } from '../../services/my-service-name.service';
...
constructor(
   private myServiceNameService : MyServiceNameService ) {
  }
...
```

4. Used directly the variables in the service through methods in the service to modify the varaibles values or get its values.

e.g:
in components:

```
let myVariable:string;

....
getNewValue(){
   myVariable = this.myServiceNameService.myVariable;
}
setNewValue ( newValue: string) {
   this.myServiceNameService.myVariable(newValue);
}
```

Comment: When I try to set `myVariable` from my component, I get this message, `This expression is not callable.
  Type 'String' has no call signatures.`

Comment: Maybe you have use 'String' instead of 'string' as type?

Comment: That wasn't it. See this reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45648714/how-to-access-getter-setter-accessors-from-angular-4-in-template-binding

Answer (score 2):

There could be multiple ways here:

1. You can create angular service (use @Injectable() annotation to create service). Angular service follows singleton design pattern and can be shared among multiple pages of your application. Wherever you need, just inject that service and you can access all properties/methods.
   Link how to create angular service -

   https://angular.io/guide/architecture-services
2. You can use redux concept and create a store having data & then that data could be accessible across all pages. NgRx is the best library with Angular to create store and access data wherever needed.
   NgRx link -

   https://ngrx.io/guide/store
3. You can use RxJs library to share data between peer components.
   RxJs link -

   https://rxjs.dev/guide/overview

Comment: I think it is better that he specializes first on services ... then as soon as he has taken a moment of confidence move on to RxJs ... and then to NgRx ...

Comment: That’s why added reference link to get hold on it.

Answer (score 0):

Use a shared service and create an observable inside the service, then inject this service to the components need to access this shared data and create a subscription on each component. When ever the data in the observable changes the subscribed components will get notified.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using Service itself:

1. Create a **Service**.

   In Service create a subject...

```
@Injectable({
 providedIn: 'root'
})

export class Service {

   subject = new Subject();
   
   
    sendMsg(msg: string) {
       this.subject.next(msg);
     }
   
     receivedMsg(): Observable <any> {
       return this.subject.asObservable();
     }
}
```

2. Component-1 from which we are sending the data.

   Inject the service in the constructor. then you need to pass your data as argument to **sendMsg** method.

   In ***component-1.ts***

```
    constructor(private Ser: Service) {}

    sendMsg(msg: any) { 
       this.Ser.sendMsg(msg.value); 
    }
```

3. Component-2 for receiving the data.

   Inject the service in the constructor.

```
    search: string;

    constructor(private Ser: Service) {}
    
    ngOnInit(): void { 
       
    this.Ser.receivedMsg().subscribe({
      next: (data: any)=> {
        this.search= data;
      }
    })
   }
```

You will get the data in the search variable.

Comment: I am new to Angular and If you don't mind, where should we add this service? Should it be created in one of the 2 module or in a separate module by itself