# Angular with sockets - getter every 10 seconds

Tags: angular, sockets

I have a little problem with sockets in angular.

I initialize them in my app.component.ts by calling a service(socket.init()):

```
public init() {
    this.socket = io(this.url);
}
```

In another component.ts I made a getter:

```
get test() {
    console.log('testing func');
    return true;
}
```

In view:

```
<span class="{{test}}">test</span>
```

The problem is that the getter send console message every 10seconds...
If I turn off sockets it works correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43167053/4125622

a getter method accessed in the template is run every time change detection is triggered (which may happen in the parent component but goes up through the whole DOM of your app).

This is why for expensive computations you should bind the result to a field and access that fielt instead of the method/getter in the template.

Comment: That's just an example, question is why it runs every 10 seconds :)

Comment: do you bind socket input to anything in your view? then angular triggers change detection as soon as a new object arrives from the socket (and I assume there is an update every 10 seconds)

Comment: I think thats the problem, thank you for your answer :)