# Random class for a div inside a ngFor in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I'm doing a web application in Angular 6 and I have an array of string with the name of classes for different colors. I would like to apply them to my `div` inside a `ngFor`.

My array of colors:

```
words = [
    'aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd'
  ];

bgRandom = '';

bg = [
   'bg-blue', 'bg-orange', 'bg-red', 'bg-gray', 'bg-maroon',
   'bg-info', 'bg-green', 'bg-fuchsia', 'bg-aqua', 'bg-yellow'
];

ngOnInit() {
   this.bgRandom = this.bg[Math.random() * this.bg.length];
}
```

Inside my template:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let word of words">
   <div [className]="'widget-user-header' + bgRandom">
      Hi all
   </div>
</ng-container>
```

Right now, `bgRandom` don't appear at all. Only `widget-user-header` appears correctly.

My goal is to have all the `div` with a different `bgRandom`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Math.random()` returns a random float, not an integer, so `Math.random() * this.bg.length` will not be an integer like an array index.

You need `Math.floor(Math.random() * this.bg.length)`

In addition, you have set bgRandom to a constant value in your initialiser function, so it will be the same for all iteration in your `*ngFor`.

You could try creating an array of randomly selected backgrounds, and one for each iteration:

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.bgRandom = [];
   for (let i =0; i < this.words.length; i++) {
      bgRandom.push(this.bg[Math.random() * this.bg.length]);
   }
}
```

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let word of words; let i = index">
   <div [className]="'widget-user-header' + bgRandom[i]">
      Hi all
   </div>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: You are right, thanks. All my `div` now have the same bg, how can I have them with a different `bg`?

Comment: @RRGT19 Added solution to my answer

Comment: Because I had already created it, I updated the stackblitz to include the use of an array property ... but created with `Array.From`. It is here for future reference: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-random-style-deborahk

Comment: @DeborahK I didn't see that change, I'm so sorry, I just saw that your answer was deleted a fiew minutes ago. I tried your solution before your recent change but, it was causing the error that you and the other partner talked about. Thats why I decided to give this solution a try. Seeing your solution now, it's shorter, works great too.

Comment: Yes, my original answer was not "best practices", so I deleted it. *This* is the correct answer. I just updated my stackblitz to match this answer and made a slight change (because I don't like `for` statements LOL!).

Answer (score 0):

The other posts are correct. You are only setting bgRandom once, so you will only get the same background color.  Math.floor(Math.random() * this.bg.length) is also correct as @rh16 said.

Try this:

```
 getBackgroundColor() {
    return this.bg[Math.floor(Math.random() * this.bg.length)];
  }
```

and in your html

```
[ngClass]="getBackgroundColor()"
```

you can get rid of you bgRandom  property.

Comment: I assume this would have the same issue @rh16?

Comment: @DeborahK Yeah it will unfortunately. Since the post has been deleted, the issue is with binding method calls to a template that will return different values even with nothing else changing, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43167053/3125245)