# getter method VS get syntax in Angular template

Tags: angular, typescript, performance, getter

Say in my view I want to get some private properties foo and bar from a class inside my template. I could use a get method or [the get syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get).

```
class Example {

  private $foo = 'foo';
  private $bar = 'bar';

  public getFoo() {
    return this.$foo;
  }

  public get bar() {
    return this.$bar;
  }

}
```

Assuming `example` is an instance of the class above, I can now do inside my template:

```
<span>{{example.getFoo()}} {{example.bar}}</span>
```

How do these two solutions differ in performance and change detection? Or is there no difference?

Comment: Interesting. Drop a console log in each and see? Should be pretty easy to tell which one is firing more if either are.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular 2 templates methods vs getters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43166792/angular-2-templates-methods-vs-getters)

Comment: Thanks @Shlang, I didn't find that question myself. It is more or less answering the question. I marked mine as a duplicate...