# Angular getFoo() vs get foo. Is there a benefit to getter/setter syntax, or is it just preference?

Tags: angular, typescript, getter-setter

My background is primarily in Java, so I'm very used to using getter/setter methods, but in Angular I know there is a different getter/setter syntax. Is this purely a preference, or are there performance benefits? Does it enhance change detection in some way?

A hypothetical example would be:

```html
<div>
  {{this.foo}}
</div>
```

```js
get foo() {
  return this.object.foo !== null ? this.object.foo : '';
}
```

VS

```html
<div>
  {{this.getFoo()}}
</div>
```

```js
getFoo() {
  return this.object.foo !== null ? this.object.foo : '';
}
```

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate of [Angular 2 templates methods vs getters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43166792/angular-2-templates-methods-vs-getters). Change detection will benefit if you use plain fields and update them.